# Calling Borland C++ Builder application from ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c++builder

I'm new to Borland C++ Builder and the application that I'm working on has to be launched from a ASP.net application on click of a button. That ASP.net application is able to launch other EXEs (made in C#) but when my application is launched it crashes immediately with a msg "an error has is encountered, please tell microsoft about this problem" with button  "Don't Send" "Send error report" and "debug". The ASP.net program is able to call "notepad.exe" which is probably not written on .net.

So, how do I call an application from ASP.net/c# which written in Borland C++ Builder and is launching successfully when I double click the application.

Comment: why is this tagged 'javascript'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the Event Log for more information on what caused the error, my guess is that it cannot load the c++ dll.